# iCloud Drive REST API

Tags: cloudkit, icloud-drive

can you suggest some keywords about the feature: upload file to iCloud Drive via REST API (POST method)? I did a lot of research in two days and I almost thought it impossible, so I come here to get help from you guys.

My project required upload the file into each user's iCloud Drive/Google Drive. For now, I'm finished with Google Drive and it works well.

I found CloudKit but seem it's not allowed to upload the file into each user drive like Google Drive

The workflow of my feature:

Step 1. Upload file to iCloud Drive via REST API

Step 2. Get the public share link from the uploaded file in Step 1

CloudKit, Key-value store, iCloud Documents Container